# Не создаются границы блоков CSS

Tags: html, css, blocks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Блоки</title>
      <link href="block3.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="one">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
        <p class="two">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
        <p class="three">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
    </body>
</html>




p.one {
    border-width: 2px;
}
p.two {
    border-width: thick;
}
p.three {
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
}
```

[image: блоки с границами]

Comment: В ссылке на css файл все указано правильно

Comment: p .one {
    border-width: 2px;
}
p .two {
    border-width: thick;
}
p .three {
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
}

Вот так сделай

Comment: @JZ_52, почитайте про селекторы, в вашем случае про [потомков](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), т.к. ваш пример вообще не решит проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо border-width Вы должны указать border-style и border-color. Только тогда граница появится. Лучше это делать короткой записью, например: `border: 2px solid black;`

```css
p.one {
    /*border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;*/
    border: 2px solid black;
}
p.two {
    border-width: thick;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: green;
}
p.three {
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
<p class="two">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
<p class="three">Клавинет Хонера - это "электрифицированная" версия клавикорда.</p>
```